# Insert a base64 image as wordpress post attachment

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm converting a canvas in a base64 png image and now I would like to add this image as a post attachment. This is my image in server-side:

```
    $image = 
base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data['pdf_thumbnail_'.$item_id]));
```

I would like to use `wp_insert_attachment()` to add this image as an attachment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// @new
$upload_path = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $upload_dir['path'] ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$decoded = $image;
$filename = 'my-base64-image.png';

$hashed_filename = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;

// @new
$image_upload = file_put_contents( $upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded );

//HANDLE UPLOADED FILE
if( !function_exists( 'wp_handle_sideload' ) ) {
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

// Without that I'm getting a debug error!?
if( !function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) ) {
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php' );
}

// @new
$file             = array();
$file['error']    = '';
$file['tmp_name'] = $upload_path . $hashed_filename;
$file['name']     = $hashed_filename;
$file['type']     = 'image/png';
$file['size']     = filesize( $upload_path . $hashed_filename );

// upload file to server
// @new use $file instead of $image_upload
$file_return = wp_handle_sideload( $file, array( 'test_form' => false ) );

$filename = $file_return['file'];
$attachment = array(
 'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
 'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
 'post_content' => '',
 'post_status' => 'inherit',
 'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename)
 );
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename );
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/tjhole/3ddfc6cbf6da01c7ce0f)

Comment: This solution is a great work https://gist.github.com/cyberwani/ad5452b040001878d692c3165836ebff

Answer (score 4):

** I have used this code, so this working properly  Use this code:**

```
        //HANDLE UPLOADED FILE
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $upload_dir['path'] ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,",$_POST['image']);
    $decoded = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $filename = 'wigo.png';
   $hashed_filename = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;
    $image_upload = file_put_contents( $upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded ); 
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');


        // Without that I'm getting a debug error!?




        $file             = array();
        $file['error']    = '';
        $file['tmp_name'] = $upload_path . $hashed_filename;
        $file['name']     = $hashed_filename;
        $file['type']     = 'image/png';
        $file['size']     = filesize( $upload_path . $hashed_filename );
        // upload file to server

        // use $file instead of $image_upload
        $file_return = wp_handle_sideload( $file, array( 'test_form' => false ) );
        $filename = $file_return['file'];
        $attachment = array(
                                             'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
                                             'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
                                             'post_content' => '',
                                             'post_status' => 'inherit',
                                             'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename)
                                             );



        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename );
        /// generate thumbnails of newly uploaded image


        $attachment_meta = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$attachment_meta);
        set_post_thumbnail($post_id,$attach_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, my solution.

```
function upload_base64_file($base64_image, $post_id)
        {
            if (empty($base64_image) || empty($post_id)) return false;


            // Base64-encoded image data

            // Decode the Base64 image data
            $image_data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $base64_image));

            // Determine the upload directory
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $image_name = '/avatar' . time() . '.jpg';
            $image_path = $upload_dir['path'] . $image_name;

            // Save the image to the specified location
            if (file_put_contents($image_path, $image_data)) {
                // Изображение успешно сохранено

                // Add the image to the WordPress Media Library
                $attachment = array(
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg', // Замените на соответствующий MIME-тип
                    'post_title' => $image_name, // Замените на желаемый заголовок
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                );

                $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $image_path, $post_id);

                if (!is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $image_path);
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attachment_data);


                    return [
                        "status" => ($attach_id !== 0) ? "success" : "error",
                        'name_file' => $image_name,
                        'attach_id' => $attach_id
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
```